# socket.io impact on ubuntu server performance

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, ubuntu-18.04

I have tried several times to scale my chat application with `socket.io`. I hit some kind of wall when trying to establish more than 2k web-socket connections on the same machine. This number seems a bit low considering that my local machine is an 8 core 6 GB of rams and during the test, only half the ram and the CPU are used. Being a nob to web-socket and Linux I might have not configured my server perfectly so far I raised the max number of open files to 500000 and max number of the open socket (maxconn) to 60000 with no effect.

So my questions are:-

1. How this will impact server performance?
2. How many more requests/sec this will cause on my server?
3. Is there a limit in the number of connections that can be created locally using `socket.io`?
4. How many concurrent connections have you been able to establish on a single machine using this kind of setup?
5. Are there any other Linux settings to tweak in order to improve performance?

Currently, I am using `Ubuntu 18.04` and my application in `node.js`.

Comment: Do you get an error regarding what is happening here? It might be that you run out of file descriptors, but it might also mean that opening thousands of tcp sockets overloads your router. Does the same code work on localhost? How about the LAN?

Comment: It's very hard to find the solution to your issue with only this info. I would recommend to install a monitoring tool on your instance. There is a good chance you will catch some weird behaviors this way. I have had good experience using https://github.com/netdata/netdata

Comment: Start by refactoring your code. For example remove 'Sync' functions (ie readFileSync) and replace them with callback code. And use Async/Await. You'll start to see other cores kicking in then.

Comment: @gergelykalman everything is working fine on localhost. But need to know about server.

Comment: @ofirule Thanks. I will install and let you know.

Comment: @WLGfx I have used `async/await` function. I was not using `sync` function.